# Цветной вывод в консоль с++

Tags: c++, linux, консоль, library

Мне нужно придать некоторые эфекты выведенному в консоль тексту. Нужно его окрасить, помигать им, сместить к центру консоли. Можно ли окрасить вывод с помощью стандартных средств с++? Есть ли сторонние библиотеки, помогающие совершать подобного рода действия? Работаю на linux

Comment: Стандартных - нет.

Comment: Когда-то был `conio.h`, а теперь `Windows.h`. Про линукс не в курсе.

Comment: @Harry, а не стандартных?

Comment: [Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal) можно почитать про это

Comment: самым используемым кросплатформенным решением, если не ошибаюсь, является curses. Он сишный и очень простой. Есть две наиболее распрастраненные библиотеки: ncurses (обычно используется на linux) и pdcurses (обычно используется на windows) - api у них одна и та же

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал termcolor для C++ [тык](https://github.com/ikalnytskyi/termcolor)

Использование очень простое:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <termcolor/termcolor.hpp>

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    std::cout << termcolor::red << "Hello, ";
    std::cout << termcolor::color<100> << "Colorful ";
    std::cout << termcolor::color<211, 54, 130> << "World!";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Подробнее можно прочитать в документации [PDF](https://termcolor.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/)

По мне выглядит вполне достойно:
[image: фото с гитхаба]

Что бы помигать вам нужно использовать метод
termcolor::nocolorize

и

termcolor::colorize

Чистить консоль и менять методы друг на друга

Comment: А что делают эти два метода, не могу найти нормальное описание?

Comment: @DenverToha (ну и заодно для BlueScreen), мигающий == blink

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я попробовал blink() ничего не происходит, как им пользовтаься?

Comment: @DenverToha, так, как написано в документации. если не работает — пишите сообщение об ошибке автору библиотеки. не забудьте приложить 1. значение переменной окружения TERM. 2. информацию о том, где именно используете библиотеку: в виртуальном терминале или в эмуляторе терминала (соответственно, укажите название и версию эмулятора).

Comment: для Linux - это обертка ANSI_escape_code.

Comment: Если перенаправить это в конвейер или поток...

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать [ANSI_escape_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) для Linux, MacOS, Unix-like, Windows 10 :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "\e[1;31m This is red text \e[0m" << std::endl;    
}
```

Можно менять не только цвет текста, но и фона, есть подчеркивание, подмигивание и т.д.

Comment: На bash так делал. Наверно, самый простой и правильный способ. Правда, я бы это обернул в класс.

Comment: @megorit, все верно, с классом удобнее.